# How can I still use an external mouse with the Lenovo X1 Yoga in tablet mode?

Tags: 18.04, mouse, lenovo, tablet

When I fold the screen back on my Lenovo X1 Yoga using Ubuntu 18.04, both the internal mouse (touchpad) and an external USB mouse are completely disabled.  Presumably, the mouse is being disabled in order to keep the internal touchpad from messing things up when using the laptop as a tablet (the touchscreen still works correctly) - but I'd still like to be able to use an external mouse while the laptop is folded. With my Yoga installed under Ubuntu 16.04, the external mouse still works while in tablet mode.

I've scoured `dconf-editor` (the `/org/onboard/auto-show/tablet-mode-detection-enabled` flag has no effect), played around with `xinput` props, and searched for any indication of where I might be able to configure this behavior, but haven't yet found anything that controls the tablet mode mouse behavior.  Any pointers?

Edit: Here's the output of `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i tablet`:

```
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.tablet area [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.tablet keep-aspect false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.tablet left-handed false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.tablet mapping 'absolute'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.tablet display ['', '', '']
org.gnome.power-manager info-last-device '/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/tablet_wacom_battery_0'
org.onboard.auto-show tablet-mode-leave-key 0
org.onboard.auto-show tablet-mode-state-file-pattern '1'
org.onboard.auto-show tablet-mode-enter-key 0
org.onboard.auto-show tablet-mode-state-file ''
org.onboard.auto-show tablet-mode-detection-enabled true
```

Comment: Because it worked in 16.04 and doesn't work in 18.04 I think you can post this as a bug on launchpad.net.

Comment: What's the output of `gsettings list-recursively | grep --ignore-case tablet`?  After [edit]ing that into your Q, please ping me @Fabby

Comment: @Fabby gsettings output added above.

Comment: I don't have your hardware, so this is a wild guess: What happens if you do a `gsettings set org.onboard.auto-show tablet-mode-leave-key ['<Control><Shift><Super><Alt>F12']` and then press that key (or another *less complicated* key combination that is not used for anything else?)  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby the setting takes its type as an integer, not a string describing a key combination.  I'm searching for a way to map a key combination to an integer, but haven't found any documentation on that yet.  It looks promising: "When this key-press is received, stop auto-show indefinitely. A convertible device might signal entering laptop-mode that way."  Though this might just pertain to the on-screen keyboard ("Onboard") rather than other tablet features.

Comment: OK, well, then I'm out of ideas, so +1 to your question because it's smart enough that I'm no use, so *it must be a good question!*  **;-)**